# Fibonacci numbers between two inputs

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am having difficulties with my homework... "Write a program that will ask the user about two numbers: Lower and Upper. Your program should print all the Fibonacci numbers in the range from lower to upper and the sum of the all the even numbers in the Fibonacci series." I don't know how to get the numbers BETWEEN the two inputs. Now it just gives numbers from zero to...?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter lower bound:");
    int lower = Integer.parseInt(scr.nextLine());
    System.out.println ("Enter upper bound:");
    int upper = Integer.parseInt(scr.nextLine());

    int fiboCounter = 1;
    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;
    int fibo = 0;
    int oddTotal = 1;
    System.out.println("The fibonacci numbers between ");
    while(fiboCounter < upper)
    {
        fibo= first + second;
        first = second;
        second = fibo;
        if(fibo % 2 == 0) 
            oddTotal = oddTotal + fibo;

        System.out.print(" "+ fibo+ " ");
        fiboCounter++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total of even Fibos: "+ oddTotal);
}
```

Comment: First, calculate your Fibonacci numbers as usual, stop when you exceed the upper bound (using loop). Inside the loop, in addition to calculate the Fibonacci number, then only print out if it is larger than lower.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check whether the calculated number is big enough:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter lower bound:");
    int lower = Integer.parseInt(scr.nextLine());
    System.out.println ("Enter upper bound:");
    int upper = Integer.parseInt(scr.nextLine());

    // This is how you can initialize multiple variables of the same type with the same value.
    int fiboCounter, second, oddTotal = 1;
    int first, fibo = 0;

    System.out.println("The fibonacci numbers between ");
    while( fiboCounter < upper ) {
        fibo= first + second;
        first= second;
        second=fibo;
        if(fibo%2==0) oddTotal=oddTotal+fibo;

        // Just check if its high enough
        if(fibo > lower ) {
            System.out.print(" "+ fibo + " ");
        }
        fiboCounter++;
    }

    System.out.println("\nTotal of even Fibos: "+ oddTotal);
    // The \n is just the same as System.out.println()

    // You probably want to close the scanner afterwards
    scanner.close();
}
```

I fixed the code a bit and made it a bit more readable.